# Mobile app works on Visual Studio Android Emulator but not on Bluestacks

Tags: android, mobile, maui

I'm working on a .net maui app distributed by a vendor that provides the source code.
Earlier I tested their app by loading the android version onto Bluestacks emulator and it works just fine. Also, I have compiled their source code, and the resulting app works just fine on the visual studio emulator.

Here is the problem: When I try to install the generated .apk file from visual studio onto Bluestacks, it installs, but it does not run.

I don't get an error. How do I find what the problem is?